# WP - ajax call responseText with unwanted HTML element

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm currently working on wordpress 8 and trying to make an Ajax call.

I've created my JS file calling ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: adminAjax,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'add_program_button',
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
```

I've created my hook in my php plugin file
`add_action('wp_ajax_add_program_button', [$this, 'my_callback']);`

My callback :

```
function my_callback(){
  ob_start();
  include __DIR__ . '/my_php_file.php';
  $html = ob_get_clean();

  wp_send_json_success(['html' => $html]);
}
```

But here is my `json.stringify(response/error)` in a console.log in my JS file:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"</div>{\"html\":\"<p>XX<\\/p>\"}","status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}
```

I don't get where this `</div>` in the responseText comes from and why it is send in the response.

I've looked for every call of the ajax hook, and there no call anywhere else.

I've tried removing the call to the file and sending manual HTML, it still adds the "div".

Comment: It comes before the actual JSON data in the response you are getting, so I'm guessing it comes from outside `my_callback` already. Anything during your plugin's initialization create any output already?

Comment: @CBroe Nope. No closing `div` in any of my plugin file except in the so called html file I send as a response.

Comment: @CBroe 
I thought it was probably something calling the ajax hook of `my_callback` and injecting it in, or maybe something hooking the `wp_send_json_success()`... But I can't find anything related

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found my own answer after a few hours of searching into hooks and everything, I'm posting the response in case someone needs it one day.

There was a closing `</div>` tag outside of the theme I was using that was out of a function.
I asked the theme creator to correct it obviously